# Capture words between two special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this:

```
"some string, some $special$ string, some string, some string, some $special$ string,..."
```

I need to capture all words between two `$` notation and put words inside `<code></code>` tag. The result of above string should be this:

```
"some string, some <code>special</code> string, some string, some string, some <code>special</code> string,..."
```

How can I do this via javascript or jquery?

Comment: have you tried using a split and replace function?

Comment: ^I would strongly suggest attempting a solution by yourself, even if it doesn't work, before asking others for one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use replace function and simple regexp:

```
'your text ...'.replace(/\$(.+?)\$/g, '<code>$1</code>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `regex` in `replace` as follow:

```
var myStr = "some string, some $special$ string, some string, some string, some $NotSospecial$ string,...";

myStr = myStr.replace(/\$(\w+)\$/g, '<code>$1</code>');
```

1. `\$` : This will escape `$` for exact match
2. `(\w+)`: Capturing group: will match any characters any no. of time
3. `g`: Global match. to continue even after first match
4. `$1`: The match from capturing group

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/o5yn5ast/

Comment: Good explanation i like it

Answer (score 0):

Using regex, and an overload of [`string.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) which takes a regular expression and a replacer function:

```js
var re = /\$(.*?)\$/g;
var input = "some string, some $special$ string, some string, some string, some $special$ string,...";
var result = input.replace(re,function(match,g1){
    return "<code>" + g1 + "</code>";
});

alert(result);
```